# Delegate does not get called

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I have a `UIPageViewController` which I setup in the `viewDidLoad` method of the RootViewController as follows:

```
[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
```

The delegate `pageViewControllerspineLocationForInterfaceOrientation` is called successfully and I can set the spine accordingly.

However, I want to setup the PageViewController on a button click so I moved the code to the event handler of the button pressed event. Now the delegate is not called.

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: A few more details would be really helpful. How is the button created exactly? Do yo know for a fact that the method is called when you click the button for instance? Where does the button reside?

Comment: I created the button in the rootview controller using the storyboard and have verified that the method is called by setting breakpoint there.

Comment: I think I know what is going on here. Since the delegate is to related to orientation change event. When the button is clicked the orientation is already set and doesn't change so the delegate is not called. I need to find a way to get the same thing done without this delegate I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It is some what complicated but can be achieved through the code below :

Step 1: Add below code to .h file of rootViewController.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *previousClick;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *nextClick;
```

Step 2: Connect them to the xib or storyboard which ever you use.

[image]

Step 3: Add two IBAction methods to .m file.

```
#pragma mark - IBAction Methods

- (IBAction)previousClick:(id)sender
{
    [_modelController pageViewController:self.pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:_dataViewController];
}


- (IBAction)nextClick:(id)sender
{
    [_modelController pageViewController:self.pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:_dataViewController];
}
```

Step 4: You also need to put below lines too to .m file

```
@interface RootViewController ()
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) ModelController *modelController;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) DataViewController *dataViewController;
@end
```

And synthesize them as below

```
@synthesize modelController = _modelController;
@synthesize dataViewController = _dataViewController;
```

Step 5: Last and final add below line to `- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation` method.

```
_dataViewController = currentViewController;
```

after the currentViewController's alloc init call.

If you find that the added buttons are hidden by the pageViewController just bring them to the front using the code below in side the `-viewDidLoad` method

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.previousClick];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.nextClick];
```